# Converting floor jack to tranny jack?

Tags: transmission, jack

Is it possible to adapt/convert a regular floor jack to a tranny jack for the purposes of lowering the transmission assembly?

Comment: It depends on the stability of the floor jack, but sure. I've done it before. It also depends on the height of the transmission and the lift of the jack as well. Remember, you have a transmission *and* a transfer case you have to drop. Usually easier to drop as one, but you could probably get away with dropping both separately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ***differences*** between the floor jack and the tranny jack:

1. Tranny Jack has 4 points on a metal plate that can be adjusted to change the angle of the tranny jack and how it meets up with the transmission.  This feature is necessary.
2. Tranny jack has a very wide stance to prevent a top heavy jack from falling over with an incredibly heavy item.  A wider base is welcome and IMO necessary.

***Other Notable Attributes***

1. Minimum Height - Getting a tranny jack under the vehicle if you don't have a lift is key.  Minimum height can be important depending on the make of the vehicle.
2. Max Height - If your working on an F350 Powerstroke max height will be very important.

## The Challenge

I think the biggest hurdle is creating a jack that is stable.  I would only use a tranny jack, not a conversion.  I've seen trannie's fall over because the right tool wasn't used or a bunch of guys were just trying to manhandle it.  If you do a conversion I believe the adjustable plate and a solid base (on wheels) are key to success.  The height component is a clear variable that depends on the make and model of the car.  If the a tranny jack is too high at it's min height you can always put the car on jackstands.  Which, in it's own way, can also be a bit nerve racking.  I prefer to have exactly the right tool for a job like this where injury is a real possibility.

*I'm sure there is an auto store where you can rent one in your area.*